# How to Process single csv file multiThreaded without splitting it using Spring-Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring batch in order to process a csv file.

Thats my step in my job:

```
 @Bean
    public Step processSnidUploadedFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
                .<MyItem, MyItem>chunk(1) //important to be one in this case to commit after every line read
                .reader(..)

                .processor(processor(...))
                .writer(writer)
                .taskExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationService.taskExecutor())   
               .build();
    }
```

as you can see I added taskExecutor in order to have multiple threads that read lines from the same file to have a faster execution.

```
public class BatchConfiguration implements InfrastructureConfigurationService {
..
 @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
```

Now for a test purpose inside my writer() I added Thread.sleep(10000) to see that I actually running in parallel(reading multiple lines from the file in parallel):

```
 @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyItem> items) throws Exception {

        for (MyItem item : items) {
            log.info(item.toString();
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        }
```

1. As soon as I invoke the Thread.sleep(..) line the whole job is stuck.. (I cant see that method invoked by other threads  - in my example 4 threads
2. I read that I need to split the file into small files and than use partition? is that the way how to do it? am I missing anything??

Thank you.

Comment: FlatFileItemReader is is not thread-safe as well as FlatFileItemWriter (from javadoc)

Comment: But still.. why my code is not multithreaded? why I am being stuck on the write(..) method and I cant see it invoked 4 times(I allocated 4 threads in my executors pool)